# How to shrink column in cross axis direction flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to design a chat page where its messages have a text and time. here's the design:

[image]

but in flutter, when I use `Column` to show time and receive checks under message text (in small messages like 'hi'), the message box expands to whole screen in cross axis direction(according to `Column` behavior) like this:

[image]

how can I handle this with the exact alignments like the first image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, wrap your column in a Container and add Constraints to give it a maximum width. then inside use the same column. Here is my Example:

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.teal,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Text(
            'This is just a dummy long text,This is just a dummy long text,This is just a dummy long text,This is just a dummy long text',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Text('9:30 AM',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Output Screenshot:**

| *Long text example* | *Short text example* |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: it doesn't work for me like your screenshots, it still expands to whole screen

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, excellent first answer! Have an upvote :D

Comment: @MahdiArabpour Please attach your code so that I can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: the proplem was that the messages where list view items so they where expanded. i wrapped the container with a row and the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

It would be expensive but you can wrap your column with **IntrinsicWidth**